# How to detect locked fields on a form?

Tags: itext, itext7

I need to detect locked fields which placed on pdf form. I'm using `itext 7.1.8` and I couldn't find any mentions or info about locked fields. 
I have the following input data: 1) Pdf document URL. I need to read this PDF and check if is form exist and after that detects locked fields existence.
I have the code looks like the following:

```
public boolean hasLockedFields(final String pdf) {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(path));
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(pathToSave));
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
    // and there I need to check locked fields in pdf.
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *locked* fields?

Comment: @mkl I think he means the lock flag `(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED)`. In itext before 7 it was like this: `Item item = PdfReader.getReader().getAcroFields().getFieldItem(fieldName); 
PdfDictionary d = item.getMerged(0);
PdfNumber num = d.getAsNumber(PdfName.F);
boolean locked = num == null ? false : ((num.intValue() & PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED) == PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED);` But in iText 7 this probably changed...

Comment: @Lonzak You are right

Comment: Ah, ok. Because it could also have been a matter of field locking in the course of signing.

Comment: @mkl This is the next step. First of all, I'm going to process all read-only fields and after that, I would like to process fields that refer to signing fields.